# Android studio throwing error when installed new parse sdk

Tags: android-studio, parse-android-sdk

I tried to use a new parse sdk from github but after installing android studio throwing below error.

Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Attaching the gradle files. Please help if there are any issues to be fixed.

App gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ashwini.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.23.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


Module gradle:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'http://jitpack.io'}
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"


}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: The file which you are referring as module level grade file is actually your root level grade file and vice versa.

Comment: I'm curious why are not you using `implementation` instead of the old `compile`

Comment: Also it is android studio 2.3.3, so i'm getting compile instead of implementation.